# Linux USB driver probe not called if device already plugged

Tags: linux, usb, driver, probe

If I use a modified usb skeleton driver on Linux and I insmod the module with the USB device already plugged in, the probe function doesn't get called. I need to unplug and replug the device in order for the driver to be activated.
This is not the case for e.g. the serial drivers, I made some tests.
Is there a reason for this? How do I get the probe function to get called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some software from us was opening the device from /proc/bus/usb and the device was claimed by the usbfs driver, so the new driver couldn't claim the device.

Answer (score 4):

Almost all USB HID devices are automatically managed by usbhid driver. Try the following:

```
sudo rmmod usbhid
sudo insmod your_driver
sudo insmod usbhid
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to unbind your device from usbhid and bind it to your driver:

- try to find the thief driver in : `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/`
- unbind it : `echo -n "1-1:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/unbind`
- bind your device :

  - `echo <vendor> <product> > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/my_driver/new_id` 
    or if you already have a bus id :
  - `echo -n "1-1:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/my_driver/bind`

see http://www.ha19.no/usb/
see http://lwn.net/Articles/143397/